# EntityFramework and update-database stopped working

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I had everything working nicely using EF and code first until I changed the configuration class to add some extra seed data and then tried

```
Update-Database
```

Now I get the below error each time.

> *Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)*

I can connect and view the database in the sql object explorer and even view the tables and data. I'm at a loss and about to give up code first and goto db first or maybe even stored procedures soon.

My connection string looks like this

```
<add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDbContext.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Is the context in a different project to where the connection string is defined?

Comment: Some project, name has stayed the same too. Just stopped working and get errors around access to the sql server

Comment: What does the constructor for your context look like?

Comment: Also does it work if you use this command: `Update-Database -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext`?

Comment: Thats strange I use -ConnectionStringName switch and copied the string out the config file and I go the error "No connection string name 'MyDbContext' could be found!

Comment: My context doesn't have a constructor as its named the same as the connection string

Comment: Damn, I set the project as the startup project and then ran the command and it looks like its all worked now! Grrrr. I assumed selecting the project from Default project: selection dropdown did this but obviously not.

Answer (score 1):

Damn, I set the project as the startup project and then ran the command and it looks like its all worked now! Grrrr. I assumed selecting the project from Default project: selection dropdown did this but obviously not.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify connection string via ConnectionString parameter:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString "data source=server_name;initial catalog=db_name;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -Verbose
```

Also you need to use this parameter with the same value for Add-Migration command:

```
Add-Migration Version_Name -ConnectionString "data source=server_name;initial catalog=db_name;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -Verbose
```